# Issue on connecting to MongoDB Atlas via Mongoose on the node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I have created the cluster on the MongoDB Atlas and now trying to create the db connect to it using the connection string provided on the Atlas.

**My Connection String on key.js file:**

```
   module.exports = {
          //mongoURI: "mongodb://DEVELOPER:DEV1234@devconnector"
          mongoURI:
            "mongodb+srv://USERNAME:PWD@devconnector-7dd46.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true"
        };
```

**Server.js file, DB Connect:**

```
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;
mongoose
  .connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDBConnected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

**Error message:**

> { Error: querySrv ESERVFAIL
>   _mongodb._tcp.devconnector-7dd46.mongodb.net
>       at errnoException (dns.js:55:10)
>       at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:243:19)   code: 'ESERVFAIL',   errno: 'ESERVFAIL',   syscall: 'querySrv',   hostname:
>   '_mongodb._tcp.devconnector-7dd46.mongodb.net' }

Just to add, I am getting the same error message while on trying to connect with Atlas from the Compass. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? Facing a similar issue.